# Is ROWLEX supports natively IEnumerable<>?

Tags: c#, .net, rdf, rowlex

Is ROWLEX supports IEnumerable? Because when I use RdfProperty(true) with string[] it is working correctly, but when I write IEnumerable< string > type of property and return string[] (that is casting implicitly to IEnumerable) and it is not working.

It is good if generic enumerables are supported, not only Array class.

Example:

```
[RdfProperty(true)]
public IEnumerable< string > TestList
{
   get
   {
      return new string[] { "First", "Second" };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [ROWLEX](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int) was written to support .NET1.1. However, ROWLEX is open source, contributions are welcome.

**EDIT: ROWLEX 2.1 is released and it does.**